# Support of quotient sheaf of ideal sheaves with same support

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals, sheaf-theory

I'm not very sure about this argument. Let $\mathscr{I},\mathscr{J}$ two ideal sheaves (you can think about ideal sheaves over a projective variety or even the projective space itself) and assume that $\mathscr{J}$ is a subsheaf of $\mathscr{I}$ with $\mathrm{supp}(\mathscr{I})=\mathrm{supp}(\mathscr {J})$.

What happens to the support of $\mathscr{I}/\mathscr{J}$?

I imagined that $\mathrm{supp}(\mathscr{I}/\mathscr J) = \varnothing$ but I'm not sure how to prove it. Can it be made switching to local rings, namely considering two ideals $I\supseteq J$ on a local (noetherian) ring $A$ with the same support as $A$-modules? That seems reasonable to me, being $$\mathrm{supp}(\mathscr{I})=\{ \text {points }p\text { such that } \mathscr{I}_p\neq 0\}$$

If the latter is true, then I'll only have to prove that for ideals as forementioned $\mathrm{supp}(I/J)=\varnothing$ holds (does this follow by some trick about radicals and factor ideals?).

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Take the variety to be one point, then $I$ and $J$ are just ideals of some ring, hence $I/J$ will be non-zero in general.

Comment: That's true, but what about the support?

Comment: The support of all three ideals will be the point of course...

Comment: There is not a single reason to believe that the support of $I/J$ should be empty...Take $R$ to be an noetherian integral domain. Then the support of any non-zero ideal is the whole spectrum. But the support of $I/J$ will never be empty, if $I \neq J$.

Comment: As elaborated in the below answer, the point is that the two ideals might have the support, but their corresponding stalks at that point could be very different. Hence the quotient stalk might be non zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $A=\mathbb Z, I=\mathbb Z, J=2\mathbb Z$. $\operatorname{supp} I = \operatorname{supp} J = \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb Z$.

$\operatorname{supp} I/J = \operatorname{supp} \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z = \{(2) \} \neq \emptyset$.

Furthermore the support can have arbitrary large dimension:
Take $R$ to be the polynomial ring in $n$ variables, $I$ a maximal ideal and $J$ be a prime ideal of height $1$, contained in $I$. Then $\operatorname{supp} I/J = \mathcal V(J) = \operatorname{Spec} R/J$ is $(n-1)$-dimensional.

Comment: Thank you for the counterexample. Do you know if something can be said about that support? For instance, is possible to prove that it is zero-dimensional?

Comment: No, why should it be??